# Checking if route parameter is being called

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

In a route filter im trying to determine if a route parameter has been called, it could possibly be NULL but i still need to know if its being called...

e.g.

```
if( // IS ROUTE "job" being called ? ) {

    if( is_null($job = $route->getParameter('job')) ) {

        return App::abort(404, 'This job does not exist.'); // Show the not found page
    }
    elseif( $job->agency->id != $agency->id ) {

        return App::abort(403, 'You are not authorized to view this job.'); // Show the insufficient permissions page
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by words "route parameter"? Is that URL parameter?

Comment: a parameter to a route as in a variable that is being applied to that route... AKA 

    Route::post('{agency}/job/view/{job}', 'Controllers\Agency\JobController@postEdit');

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my own problem, im not sure if its the conventional or elegant way:

```
in_array('job', $route->getParameterKeys())
```

this check if the route parameter 'job' has been called on the current route. Very useful.

my previous code now looks like:

```
if( in_array('job', $route->getParameterKeys()) ) {

    if( is_null($job = $route->getParameter('job')) ) {

        return App::abort(404, 'This job does not exist.'); // Show the not found page
    }
    elseif( $job->agency->id != $agency->id ) {

        return App::abort(403, 'You are not authorized to view this job.'); // Show the insufficient permissions page
    }   
}
```